# CloudFlare WAF blocks webservice calls with non-English chars

Tags: security, firewall, cloudflare

I am using CloudFlare WAF in `High` security mode. When I make webservice calls which includes some non-English characters such as Ö,Ç the application firewall blocks it and returns;

```
You can email the site owner to let them know you were blocked. Please include what you were doing when this page came up and the CloudFlare Ray ID found at the bottom of this page

CloudFlare Ray ID: 2366df772ee32bbe
```

When I turn the security level to `Low`, the webservice is accepted.

How can I find which specific rule causes that error when I am using it with `High` security mode?

Answer (score 0):

I see the same problem. Here is what I did to see the rules triggered:

- Did a test call to the web service.
- After a few hours, looked into the traffic report and found my ip's block entry.
- Clicked on Details and could see which rules were triggered.